# Can you put a blockquote inside another blockquote?

Tags: html

I have a situation where I want to quote a person that eventually quotes from an article. Can I put a blockquote inside another blockquote, and will it be html valid?

> ...some text
>
> > ...some other text
>
> ...some text

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea says no problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is valid to put a blockquote inside a blockquote:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote

Permitted Content: [Flow Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content)

> Elements belonging to the flow content category typically contain text or embedded content. They are: `…, <blockquote>, …`